# Perfect Polarization filter

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, polarization

Since no component is 100% perfect, wouldn't there be non selected polarized orientations that make it through a polarizing filter of a selected orientation?

Or to put it another way, how accurate is the orientation of the filtered photon's polarisation?

Thank you for your replies.
My thoughts were, Only a perfect 0 deg filter will block a 90 deg orientation. Any variance off that 0 degrees allows a tiny component of the 90 degree polarization. So a 0 degree filter followed by a 90 degree will still have a infinitesimal fraction of photons getting through. Not zero.

Comment: Obviously it depends... all filters are not equally efficient.

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange. Unfortunately, your question is more an engineering question than a physics question. Please check the data sheets e.g. at https://www.thorlabs.de/navigation.cfm?guide_id=24

Comment: I think it is a reasonable question for this site.

Comment: Do you understand the basic principles of how a polarizing filter works? Are you just asking about optical polarizers, or are you interested in other frequencies too? Obviously, polarizers for radio waves won't be useful for visible light, and vice versa.

Comment: [PM 2Ring] At the moment I am only imagining visible light but I do realise there is a large spectrum to the electromagnetic field. <br>A polarising filter needs the photon blocked to be converted into heat but can't the capturing electron, on rare occasions, just re-admit the photon in a slightly different polarisation. <br>Ah, So what your saying is energy is always down hill and the frequency will change as the electron will never re-admit the same frequency. There has to be entropy.

Comment: I feel like we should call light "light", or electromagnetic wave, other than "photons", especially when we are discussing polarization, one of the wave properties of light.

Comment: @verdelite why? It’s the photons that are polarized. A light wave is made of billions of coherent protons.

Comment: @BillAlsept The concept of photon does not make light not light. So light is still a proper name. It is like when we talk about electric current, we call it current, not "billions of coherent piece-wise single electron currents", or if we coin a name for them, "flowons"? It is more precise, and conservative, I feel.

Comment: @verdelite because you said especially, I was just  pointing out that it’s individual photons that are polarized and not waves.

Answer (score 1):

> how accurate is the orientation of the filtered photon's polarisation?

This obviously depends on the polarizing filter. There are no perfect polarizing filters, but not all filters are equally imperfect.

Generally, polarizing filters sold for professional-grade optics are sold together with a data sheet that gives their specifications; in this particular case the thing to look for is the *extinction ratio*, i.e. the ratio to which the blocked polarization is really blocked with respect to the allowed component (which will typically vary depending on the wavelength). [Here](https://www.thorlabs.de/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=752) is one random example for you to see what these data sheets generally look like.

So, to answer your question:

> how accurate is the orientation of the filtered photon's polarisation?

... as accurate as the data sheet of the filter in use says that it's going to be.